# How to connect current circuit?

Tags: oscillator

First of all, sorry for trivial question. While googling came across the current circuit, but I'm puzzled how to connect this circuits:
[image]

There is 4.5V out put where to connect this, and the whole circuit as well?
Is `K2` is the output of the circuit?

P.S.
Could you please mark, where am I suppose to connect?

Comment: Connect what? Where? Why? I am usually connecting schematics with staples.

Comment: You see, there 4.5V output, to what that suppose to be connected? If you mind could you please gather that in PCB?

Comment: Two points labeled the same should be connected together. It can't be an input, as it is connected to the output of an OPAMP. Can it be an output? Yes, with some constraints.

Comment: Sorry did get what you mean?

Comment: @elgolondrino, you have posted a copyright Elektor schematic! Ask your question on http://forum.elektor.com/.

Answer (score 1):

9V Battery goes in on K1. IC2.B outputs 4.5V, this connects to IC1.B and IC1.A. K2 is the output of the circuit.

Comment: Could you please, draw that in that picture?

Comment: @elgolondrino - Do you see the output labeled "4V5" at lower left? And do you see the input labeled "4V5" at upper right? Does the idea of connecting outputs and inputs with the same name seem reasonable? And how in the world are we supposed to alter your image to show connection?

Comment: O_o oophs sorry man

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast And am I suppose to connect `8` pin and `4` respectively to IC1 and IC2?

Comment: Pin 8 and pin 4 are the power and ground pins on the ICs.  The bottom part of the schematic shows the power supply for the upper part.

Comment: @elgolondrino - Sigh. What pin of what IC is the output labeled "4V5"? What pin of what IC is the input labeled "4V5"? Answer those two questions, then connect those pins.